# mongodb c# driver with GridFS and .Net garbage collection

Tags: c#, mongodb, garbage-collection, gridfs

I evaluated `GridFS APIs` using `MongoDB C# driver` for storing files.

I understand it expose streams to read and write. Just want to check if anyone encountered `.Net GC` issues in real life (*specifically around Gen2*).

I don't know the driver's internal implementation, want to make sure there are no frequent large object heap allocations.

Comment: I haven't encountered any performance issues myself, but I'm a little confused as to why this concerns you? If you use the driver properly, it will run properly.

Comment: In the past I have faced issues when big chunks of memory (> ~80kB) get allocated and de-allocated frequently. Gen-2 collection in that case brought the server performance to knees. I want to ensure such a thing is not happening here.